# Add the list of messagebox to a resource file in c#

Tags: c#

I've already wrote my code with my try catch and extra message box but now i have to put the message box into a resource file how can i do it?

This is my code:

```
  public void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // in the filepath variable we are going to put the path file that we browsed.
            filepath = txtPath.Text;
            if (filepath == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No file selected. Click browse and select your designated file.");
            }
       }
```

Comment: Do you mean the message box or the text that you are displaying?

Comment: @ScruffyDuck  the text that am displaying

Answer (score 1):

You can just add those messages as String in your main application Resource file using the designer (`Resources.resx`) and then access them using Properties namespace. Let's say you add this:

```
ErrorNoFile | "No file selected. Click browse and select your designated file."
```

You can just call it like so:

```
MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.ErrorNoFile);
```

And if you modify the entry name in the resource file, it will be automatically refactored, at least with VS2012 which is the one I'm using. Instanciating a `ResourceManager` is only good if you want to keep those messages in a separate resource, otherwise it looks like an overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a resource manager to retrieve resources.
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("items", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

// Retrieve the value of the string resource named "filepath".
// The resource manager will retrieve the value of the  
// localized resource using the caller's current culture setting.

public void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // in the filepath variable we are going to put the path file that we browsed.
            filepath = txtPath.Text;
            if (filepath == string.Empty)
            {
                String str = rm.GetString("welcome");
                MessageBox.Show(str);
            }
       }
```